# Getopt to accept special characters as values

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Getopts is not accepting the special characters as values, 
what is the better option to accept the special characters as inputs for values. when i pass the normal values the output gets printed but when I tried to pass with special characters the output is ignored.

```
optspec=":hv-:"
while getopts "$optspec" optchar; do

    case "${optchar}" in
        -)
            case "${OPTARG}" in
                SPUN=*)
                    SPUN=${OPTARG##*=}
                    ;;
                SPPWD=*)
                    SPPWD=${OPTARG##*=}
                    ;;
                SPTENT=*)
                    SPTENT=${OPTARG##*=}
                    ;;
                SECURITY_PROTOCOL=*)
                    SECURITY_PROTOCOL=${OPTARG##*=}
                    ;;
                SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=*)
                    SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=${OPTARG##*=}
                    ;;
                SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=*)
                    SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=${OPTARG##*=}
                    ;;
                INITIALIZE=*)
                    INITIALIZE=${OPTARG##*=}
                    ;;
                *)
                    echo "Unknown option --${OPTARG}" >&2
                    exit 1
                    ;;
            esac;;
        h)
            print_usage
            exit
            ;;
        v)
            echo "Parsing option: '-${optchar}'" >&2
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$OPTERR" != 1 ] || [ "${optspec:0:1}" = ":" ]; then
                echo "Non-option argument: '-${OPTARG}'" >&2
            fi
            ;;
    esac
done

echo ++ USERNAME: $SPUN
echo ++ "<><><>< $INITIALIZE"
echo ++ "$SPTENT"
echo ++ PWD: $SPPWD

deploy.sh --SPUN=sujithsujtih --SPPWD=sujithpwd= --INITIALIZE=test --SPTENT=beating
++ USERNAME: sujithsujtih
++ <><><>< test
++ beating
++ PWD:

deploy.sh --SPUN=sujithsujtih --SPPWD=I+RFzwpXm13Jn==@k2B0R*@7Xw8e5@.a --INITIALIZE=test --SPTENT=beating
++ USERNAME: sujithsujtih
++ <><><>< test
++ beating
++ PWD: @k2B0R*@7Xw8e5@.a
```

Answer (score 0):

AFIK, there is no restriction on what characters you can pass as options (with, maybe, the exception of the NUL character). I don't know what you mean by **special** characters, but be careful what the invoking shell is doing with the input, before `getopt` has a chance to see it, and how you are use the value afterwards. For instance, when you do in your code

```
--SPPWD=I+RFzwpXm13Jn==@k2B0R*@7Xw8e5@.a
```

this is inherently unsafe, because the shell will try to expand the glob character `*`. In the - admittedly unlikely - case that a file name exists matching this string, your program will see that expanded file name instead of the asterisk. Hence, you would better write it as

```
--SPPWD="I+RFzwpXm13Jn==@k2B0R*@7Xw8e5@.a"
```

or

```
"--SPPWD=I+RFzwpXm13Jn==@k2B0R*@7Xw8e5@.a"
```

The same applies on using the parsed options. When you do, like in your code, a

```
echo ++ PWD: $SPPWD
```

wildcard expansion may occur on the content of `SPPWD`, and you would better write

```
echo "++ PWD: $SPPWD"
```

But this is a general principle with bash-programming and not related to getopt.

Comment: I tried the option with passing as quotes, it didn't work 
./deploy.sh --SPUN=sujithsujtih --SPPWD="sujithpwd=" --INITIALIZE=test --SPTENT=beating
++ USERNAME: sujithsujtih
++ <><><>< test
++ beating
++ PWD:

the PWD is empty, the issue here is   optarg##= is not considering the values with special characters   
              SPPWD=*)
                    SPPWD=${OPTARG##*=}

Comment: @sujithgowda : Do a `echo "$OPTARG"`  before setting SSPWD, to verify what's stored there, and define what you mean by **special** characters.

Comment: I have minimal knowledge on this optarg , I have two values as password
--SPPWD=I+RFzwpXm13Jn==@k2B0R*@7Xw8e5@.a
--SPPWD=bY6fLR9hypXaWXklhl1u84huEBHN32JnkOmweZd3wwY=
when i pass above 2 values both the values are ignored. the firts values prints only after @ and the second values has an empty output when you echo it

Comment: So, what exactly does the `echo` print, which I told you to insert into your code?

Comment: ++ PWD: @k2B0R*@7Xw8e5@.a

Comment: So, which special character is missing in this string? Where then is the problem? BTW, you printed `$SPPWD` while I asked you to print `$OPTARG`.